# Idempotent conjecture and (weak) connectivity of (a reasonable) dual group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

What is an example of  a torsion free discrete abelian group $G$ whose dual space $\hat{G}$ is not a path connected space?

**The Motivation:**  The motivation comes from the idempotent conjecture of Kaplanski: For a torsion free and discreet abelian group $G$ the dual group $\hat{G}$ is  a connected space so $C^*_{red} G \sim C(\hat{G})$ has no nontrivial idempotent. Thus   in this case the  Kaplanski conjecture is true so this situation is a motivation for belife on idempotent conjecture of  Kaplanski.(See the  first pages of "An introduction to the Baum Connes conjecture" by  Alain Valette.  So we wish to reduce the power of connectivity as much as possible with a possible hope  of  having counter example. For example we would like to think to a possible discrete group $G$ which is torsion free and some of its [reasonable dual](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0081543810040164#author-information) or other [types of dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Dualities_for_non-commutative_topological_groups) or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/70658/36688)  would be  weak connected as much as possible.

Comment: The $p$-adic [solenoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)), i. e. duals of $\mathbb Z[\frac1p]$, are not path connected

Comment: For other examples, the inverse limits of compact connected Lie groups may be good candidates. Inverse limits of compact (resp. connected LC) groups are compact (resp. connected LC) groups, provided the connecting maps are surjective. The same is not always valid for path connectedness. p-adic solenoid is actually a representative example.

Comment: I believe the Kadison-Kaplansky conjecture is known for torsion-free abelian groups.  It is true for any group for which Baum-Connes holds and that includes abelian groups I believe.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg yes that is true for abelian group. The complete proof is given in the post for discrete abelian. In fact the surjectivity of the assembly map implies the Kaplanski conjecture. Anyway I am interested in the mitivation part of  this post too.