# Idempotent conjecture and non-abelian solenoid

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Is there a  discrete non-abelian group whose dual [in a reasonable sense](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453109/idempotent-conjecture-and-weak-connectivity-of-a-reasonable-dual-group) is isomorphic to the solenoid constructed via a sequence of quaternions $S^3$ instead of a sequence of circles? The motivation comes from [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453109/idempotent-conjecture-and-weak-connectivity-of-a-reasonable-dual-group#comment1172065_453109) answering [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453109/).

BTW does a non-abelian solenoid (being a torsion-free group) satisfy the idempotent conjecture?

Comment: You refer to "this answer to [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453109/idempotent-conjecture-and-weak-connectivity-of-a-reasonable-dual-group#comment1172065_453109)", but the link goes to a comment, and the question does not have an answer.  Did you link what you intended?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for  your  edit and  your comment. But that comment was  a  complete and  interesting answer to the  main  (first) part of the question. However the motivation part of that question is remained and  may be need to be more discussed